# how to represent a number (BigInt or Int) of an arbitrary length as Buffer in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, bigint

I am trying to do something similar to python's [int.to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) in nodeJS. 
It needs to support endian formats and signed/unsigned numbers of any size.

Node has something similar [writeBigInt](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writebigint64be_value_offset) but it only supports 64bits(8bytes) and doesn't get polyfilled to browsers (yet?).

My attempt is the following https://gist.github.com/painor/89a880ee76799ab6bbb6591195e07321
and is using the [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) package

It works sometimes but it fails on integers like `-161263069315735296n`

code :

```
function readBufferFromBigInt(bigInt, bytesNumber, little = true, signed = false) {
    bigInt = BigInt(bigInt)
    const bitLength = bigInt.bitLength()

    const bytes = Math.ceil(bitLength / 8)
    if (bytesNumber < bytes) {
        throw new Error('OverflowError: int too big to convert')
    }
    if (!signed && bigInt.lesser(BigInt(0))) {
        throw new Error('Cannot convert to unsigned')
    }
    let below = false
    if (bigInt.lesser(BigInt(0))) {
        below = true
        bigInt = bigInt.subtract(bigInt.add(bigInt))
    }

    const hex = bigInt.toString('16').padStart(bytesNumber * 2, '0')
    let l = Buffer.from(hex, 'hex')
    if (little) {
        l = l.reverse()
    }

    if (signed && below) {
        if (little) {
            l[0] = 256 - l[0]
            for (let i = 1; i < l.length; i++) {
                l[i] = 255 - l[i]
            }
        } else {
            l[l.length - 1] = 256 - l[l.length - 1]
            for (let i = 0; i < l.length - 1; i++) {
                l[i] = 255 - l[i]
            }
        }
    }
    return l
}
```